# Need help writing a formula that returns info from one cell only if two criteria are met to create a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am creating a bid sheet and need to write a formula that will return a value only if the $ amount is >0 and the corresponding row includes the word "Division". I can get it to list all rows using this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Data Fields'!B$10:B$504, SMALL(IF('Data Fields'!J$10:J$504<>"", ROW('Data Fields'!B$10:B$504)-ROW('Data Fields'!B$10)+1),ROWS('Data Fields'!B$10:B10))),"")
```

(Entered as an array)

How/where would I embed the ifs to only return the info I described. I've tried several different ways but haven't been able to return the proper info.

Comment: Could you provide a touch of sample data?  Based on your comments I believe using the SEARCH function might help.

Comment: I tried uploading screenshots but apparently I'm not allowed to do so. I need to pull data from one sheet where there is a dollar amount greater than $0 in column J and the word "division" is included in column B, and return the text in column B that will create a list of only those divisions that include a dollar amount greater than $0. I'm then using a lookup based off that info to return the $ amount for that field.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest few possible methods. Where one is applying an Array (CSE) formula and another is Advance Filter.*

[image]

**How it works:**

**Method 1:**

- Write criteria `Division` in cell `F3`.
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `E9`, finish   with  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

  ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX(A3:A19,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$3,$B$3:$B$19)*COUNTIF($C$3:$C$19,">0"),ROW(A3:A19)-MIN(ROW(A3:A19))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

---

**Method 2:**

- Copy Header in `G2:I2`.
- Enter `Division` in cell `H3`, and `=">0"` in `I3`.
- Select `A2:C19`.
- From DATA TAB hit `Advanced`.
- For Criteria select `H2:I3`
- Finally for `Copy to another location`, select single cell, here is `G8`.

[image]

- Now finsih with **Ok**.